# Calculating convolution of binomial distribution using moment generating function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convolution, binomial-distribution

I have two independent random variables $X_{1}, X_{2}$ on the same probability space. $X_{1}$ is bin bin(n, p) and $X_{2}$ ís bin (m, p) with n, m natural numbers and p in the interval [0,1].
I need to prove now, that the distribution of $X_{1}+X_{2}$ is bin (n+m, p), using the moment generating function
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]$$.
I have no idea....
Thanks for any help!

Equorne

Edit: Sorry, that I don't write any "hi" or anything at the beginning; the editor somehow always deletes it.

Comment: About the greeting being deleted, please see [this question on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213).

Answer (score 1):

The moment generating function (MGF) of $X_1$ is
$$M_{X_1}(t) = (1-p+pe^t)^n.$$
For $X_2$ it is
$$M_{X_2}(t) = (1-p+pe^t)^m.$$
The MGF of the sum of two independent random variables is the product of both MGFs, i.e.
$$
\begin{align}
M_{X_1+X_2}(t) &= (1-p+pe^t)^n (1-p+pe^t)^m\\
&= (1-p+pe^t)^{n+m}
\end{align}
$$
which is again a binomial distribution with parameters $n+m$ and $p$.

Comment: Thanks! So des this mean the MGF characterizes the distribution uniquely?

Comment: That is correct! Some examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Examples

Comment: @Equi If this answer (or any other one to come) solved your issue, please mark it as accepted ;)